# Centering a TABLE within a DIV

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

I'm looking to make this table lay in the center of its containing div and its driving me crazy! Tried to use CSS and HTML tricks to do it and nothing is working. My last effort was going to be to just add padding to the left of the columns and just eye it out but I decided to ask for some help before going to such a measure.

http://jsfiddle.net/RQXvR/

Comment: do you have a better example? your table takes up the entire width of the div that it is in

Comment: You have a class 'container' on your table which is making it take up the entire width of its parent

Answer (score 12):

try this css for your table

```
table {margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: Hi user1053263, i have seen your code and css in firefox 3.6 and your table is in center of the class="content" div. Can you please specify where exaclty you facing the problem or am i getting your ques differently. OR Do you want the alignment of table cells center aligned?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `<center> </center>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/RQXvR/8/

Take the `width: 100%;` off of the .container class, and add `margin: 0 auto;` to your table.

Answer (score 1):

how about add another div with that css property ?

Comment: i attempted to contain the table within a dv with it but nothing

Answer (score 0):

do this

Define the width of the div for example: 1000px;

so the div must have this CSS to make it center.

```
.div
{
width:1000px;
position:relative;
z-index-200;
left:50%;
margin-left: -500px;
}
```

Explanation:

margin-left = to half of the width you define.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be rude--I was just pointing out that there are syntax errors and that this won't work for one specific reason. Do you need me to tell you what the reason is?

Comment: i know. most fault of error are missing part.. thanks for correcting